# Swift parser Kanna don't see all div

Tags: html, swift, parsing, https

need some help with parsing some site. When I try to do this, I get list with divs:

```
<div class = 'container'>
<div class = 'navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse'>
<div class = 'navbar-header'>
<div class = 'navbar-collapse collapse'>
<div class = 'form-group clearfix'>
<div class = 'btn pull-right'>
<div class = 'form-group'>
<div class = 'form-group'>
<div class = 'checkbox'>
<div class = ''>
<div class = 'container main'>
```

But this is not all divs! Its must be much more!

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.ukrticket.com.ua/booking/#/guide/concert")
let URLTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
                (myData, response, error) -> Void in
                guard error == nil else { return }
                let myHTMLString = String(data: myData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: myHTMLString!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                {
                    for link in doc.css("div")
                    {
                         print("<\(link.tagName!) class = '\(link["class"] != nil ? link["class"]! : "") >")
                    }
                }
}
```

Thank's for help =)

Comment: `Its must be much more` it *must* be more or there *are* more? Which are not present?

Comment: @ieaglle sorry for my English - there are more (i get only 11 divs, but there are more then 100 )